# MongoDB .NET Core Schema

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongoose, mongodb-query

recently I started learning .NET Core and I am trying to connect to MongoDB, so far I can connect successfully, get data, update data etc.

Now I am trying to create schemas that will have rules, for example for user schema:
username - must be unique, field must be required (no way username is empty).

Now in Nodejs I know how to do it in Mongoose like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true,
        min:3,
        max:20
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        min:6,
        max:20
    },
    lastDepartment:{
        type:String,
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema)
```

But in .NET I can't figure out how to do so.

I have a model that looks like that:

```
    using MongoDB.Bson;

namespace Server.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int [] comments { get; set; }
        public int [] tags { get; set; }



    }
}
```

And I want title to be unique and required with min length of 5 chars and max of 25.
How can I do that?

I really searched all over the web for it but there are really low resources on this.
Best i got was:

```
 var keys = Builders<Question>.IndexKeys.Ascending("title");
        var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions {Unique = true}; 
        var model = new CreateIndexModel<Question>(keys, indexOptions);
        collection.Indexes.CreateOne(model);
```

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: i think you have to put some custom if else statement

Comment: May be you can use this: [MongoDB Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/).